# Why the following space is a submanifold of $\mathcal{M}_4(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

Let consider the space $\mathcal{O}:=\{X\in \mathcal{M}_4(\mathbb{R}) \ / \ ^tX DX=D \}$ with $D=diag(1,1,1,-1)$.

Maybe we can apply the submersion's criterion.

We take $f : \mathcal{M}_4(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathcal{S}_4(\mathbb{R})\simeq \mathbb{R}^{10}, \ X\mapsto \ ^tX DX-D$ and we want to prove that $\mathrm{d}f_X$ is a surjective map.

Let $H \in \mathcal{M}_4(\mathbb{R})$ :

$f(X+H) = \ ^t(X+H)D(X+H) - D = f(X) + \ ^tXDH + \ ^tHDX + \text{o}(\Vert H \Vert)$.

So $\mathrm{d}f_X(H)= \ ^tXDH + \ ^tHDX$. Then I do not know how to continue.

Note that the dimension of $\mathcal{O}$ is $6$.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Submersion is more than you need. It's enough to show that 0 is regular value of your map, that is, $df_X$ only needs to be surjjective when $X^tDX=D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** As Daniel Kruse points out in the comments, you do not need $f$ to be a submersion; it's sufficient to show that it is a submersion on $\mathcal O$, i.e., that $$df_X : T_X \mathcal M_4(\Bbb R) \to T_{f(X)} S_4(\Bbb R) \cong S_4(\Bbb R)$$ is surjective for all $X \in \mathcal O$. (Indeed, $df_0$ is the zero map and so is not surjective.)

So, we need to show that for any $X \in \mathcal O$ that any symmetric matrix $S$ can be written in the form $$S = {}^t\! XDH + {}^t\! HDX$$ for some $H$. This equation is complicated by the fact that $D$ is not the identity matrix (which is the case for the orthogonal group of the standard inner product). On the other hand, ${}^t D = D$ and $D^2 = I$, which suggests that we can simplify our condition by writing the unknown $H$ as $DA$ (i.e., setting $A = D^{-1} H = DH$).

Then, the surjectivity condition is that we can find an $A$ such that
$$S = {}^t\! XD(DA) + {}^t (DA)DX,$$
and this expression simplifies.

Incidentally, $\mathcal{O}$ is a group under matrix multiplication; in fact it is the Lorentz group $O(1, 3)$ of linear transformations that fix a light cone in Minkowski space.

Comment: Ok I see ! So we have finally that $S= \ ^tXA + \ ^tAX =\ ^tS$ with $X \in \mathcal{O}, \ A \in \mathcal{M}_4(\mathbb{R})$ !

Comment: @Maman Yes, exactly. So now all we have to do is guarantee that for any (symmetric) $S$ we can find an $A$ that makes that equation true. One way to do that is to give a formula for $A$ in terms of $S$.